# Could Not Open Site In Firefox Through Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I tried to open a site in firefox through selenium python, when i run the code it opens firefox after that nothing happens ,

WATCH THIS --> [HOW TO USE FIREFOX IN PYTHON & HOW TO SET VALUES IN DROP-DOWN LISTS?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEAsW8-_vww&t=297s)

here is the error

```
  bash-3.1$ C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/python.exe d:/PYTHONS/EXTRACT-NEWS/FFD
RIVER.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/PYTHONS/EXTRACT-NEWS/FFDRIVER.py", line 23, in <module>
    executable_path=r"D:\\PYTHONS\\DRIVERS\\geckodriver.exe")
  File "c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession
```

[WHEN I RUN THE CODE I GOT THIS ERR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEAsW8-_vww&t=297s)
HOW TO USE FF IN PYTHON?

THX IN ADVANCE

```
# Import Libraries
import os
import sys
import time

from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.firefox.options


from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# Configure Firefox Options
profile = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=r"D:\\PYTHONS\\DRIVERS\\geckodriver.exe")
# 0 means to download to the desktop, 1 means to download to the default "Downloads" directory, 2 means to use the directory

profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)

profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_path)

profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)

profile.set_preference(
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip/text/csv")

os.system("cls")

#  firefox_profile=profile

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

print(driver.title)

# driver.quit()


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Bf8.png
```

Comment: if you use prefix `r` (`raw`) then don't use \\  -  `r"D:\PYTHONS\DRIVERS\geckodriver.exe"`. OR use \\ without prefix `r` - `"D:\\PYTHONS\\DRIVERS\\geckodriver.exe"`

Comment: @furas  ok , thx a lot

Comment: @furas  i removed  prefix r , still getting same err, it didnt open a site , wht 2do?

Comment: first time I see someone use `webdriver.Firefox()` two times in code. To set preference you would need rather `webdriver.FirefoxProfile()` instead of `webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: @furas  i'm a beginner ,

Answer (score 0):

To set preference you have to use `FirefoxProfile()` instead of `Firefox()`

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '.')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip/text/csv")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path="D:\\PYTHONS\\DRIVERS\\geckodriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

print(driver.title)
```

BTW: and don't run `webdriver.Firefox()` two times beacuse Selenium doesn't know how to run two browsers at the same time - and this gave you error message.

Comment: it didnt load webpage , address bar is blank

using vs code , python 3.5 (32 bit).

OS : WINDOWS 7 (64 bits)

Comment: whn i use chromedriver it opened site & clicked the link but couldn't set the values in dropdown lists

Comment: i want to get historical daily prices from https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/miscellaneous/multicommodityexchangeindia/MCE

Comment: it opened that link but could not set values in dropdown list .

what to do?

Comment: CODE TO SELECT MONTH :

# FRM MTH #
 time.sleep(1) 
el = dri.find_element_by_name('frm_mth') 

for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'): 
    if option.text == 'Jan': 
       option.click()

Comment: current answer resolves problem with current error message. If you have new problem then create new question on new page. You will have more space to describe new problem.

Comment: BTW: I opened this page but I don't see element with name `'frm_mth'`. If I try code with different dropdown list on different page then your code works correctly.

Comment: pls watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEAsW8-_vww&t=297s

Comment: you have to give company name & scroll down little bit ,click the link GET HISTORICAL PRICES on right-hand side

then u'll land on that page, there  u can see that element

Comment: better create new question where you can describe how to get this element - and/or in new question you can put direct link to page with this element.

Comment: did u watch my youtube video?

Comment: use button "Ask Question" to create new question on new page - you will have more place to describe problem, show code, and error message. Don't askt two questions on one page.